# Using pytest to do setup and teardown

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a handful of tests in my test module that need some common setup and teardown to run before and after the test.  I don't need the setup and teardown to run for *every* function, just a handful of them.  I've found I can kind of do this with `fixtures`

```
@pytest.fixture
def reset_env():
    env = copy.deepcopy(os.environ)
    yield None
    os.environ = env


def test_that_does_some_env_manipulation(reset_env):
    # do some tests
```

I don't actually need to return anything from the fixture to use in the test function, though, so I really don't need the argument.  I'm only using it to trigger setup and teardown.

Is there a way to specify that a test function uses a setup/teardown fixture without needing the fixture argument?  Maybe a decorator to say that a test function uses a certain fixture?

Comment: Decorate the test with `@pytest.mark.usefixtures('reset_env')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620104/using-pytest-to-do-setup-and-teardown?noredirect=1#comment97934047_55620104)'s comment above

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('reset_env')
def test_that_does_some_env_manipulation():
    # do some tests
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `autouse=True` in your fixture. Autouse automatically executes the fixture at the beginning of fixture scope. 
In your code:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def reset_env():
    env = copy.deepcopy(os.environ)
    yield None
    os.environ = env


def test_that_does_some_env_manipulation():
    # do some tests
```

But you need to be careful about the scope of the fixture as the fixture would be triggered for each scope. If you have all such tests under one directory, you can have it in a conftest file of the directory. Otherwise, you can declare the fixture in the test file.

[Relevant pytest help doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids)

Comment: That would run it for every test in the module, right?

Comment: Yeah, if the fixture has `scope=function`.