# Getting pytest to run setup and teardown for every test (coming from nose)

Tags: python, pytest

How do I make this test suite (see below) run `setup` and `teardown` with every test?

```
import system

def setup():
    system.bootstrap()  # create vanilla installation.

def teardown():
    system.reset()  # reset installation.

def test01():
    # <-- expects setup()
    system.create_user('bob')
    assert 'bob' in system.directory
    # <-- expects teardown() even when the assertion fails.

def test02():
    # <-- expects setup()
    system.create_user('jane')
    assert 'jane' in system.directory
    # <-- expects teardown() even when the assertion fails.
```

I'm sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620104/using-pytest-to-do-setup-and-teardown) answer is close, I just can't get it to work in VScode on windows-11.
I've looked at [how to implement xunit-style set-up](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/xunit_setup.html) in the docs, but no function is passed. The testing is very `functional`.

What I see is that test01 runs with `setup` and `teardown`, but not test02.

What is missing in my mental model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your solution works, I would recommend the use of a  pytest fixture --

```
import system

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def handle_system():
    system.bootstrap()
    yield
    system.reset()
```

Comment: I consider this the formal answer, despite that the `setup_function` and `teardown_function` also work.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst writing the question, I found out that `pytest` runs setup and teardown if I just rename them to: `setup_function` and `teardown_function`.

No parameters required.

```
import system


def setup_function():
    system.bootstrap()  # create vanilla installation.

def teardown_function():
    system.reset()  # reset installation.

def test01():
    # <-- expects setup()
    system.create_user('bob')
    assert 'bob' in system.directory
    # <-- expects teardown() even when the assertion fails.

def test02():
    # <-- expects setup()
    system.create_user('jane')
    assert 'jane' in system.directory
    # <-- expects teardown() even when the assertion fails.
```

pytest on windows 11. Python 3.9.10. pytest 7.0.1